# How to check on screen background script processes?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a shell script running in the background on a AWS server. To get there, I used the following commands:

```
apt-get install screen   #Install screen
screen -m                #Start screen
bash myscript.sh         #Run the script
CTRL + a and then d      #Detach and run in background
```

To check on the script to see if it is still running, I use the following commands:

```
# List the detached screens
screen -ls

# Find the screen to reattach and attach
screen -r 123456
```

Is there a more elegant way to see if my background script is still running and not hung or in an error state?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pgrep <process_name>` to check if your scrip is still running.

> pgrep looks through the currently running processes and lists the
>   process IDs which matches the selection criteria to stdout. All the
>   criteria have to match.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep